# java copy Excel cell content to a word document

Tags: java, excel, ms-word

I would like to be able to copy the content of an Excel cell, let's say B3 in tab (or sheet) "my sheet" into a word document.
I know exactly where to put the content of B3 into the word document, but I don't know how I can do it using Java.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines on asking Questions in the [help]. You'll notice you're expected to have performed basic research and the code you've already tried with an exact question about *how* this code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished a project that creates an excel workbook from scratch using java. First time doing it, but I would recommend [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). To share some sources I found along the way [here is an overview of core classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_core_classes.htm) the library offers with some useful method descriptions.

And if you find this is something you may want to use [here are a bunch of examples](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html#xssf-only) that I found quite useful.

My answer is as non-technical as they come, but hopefully this is helpful in some way.

Edit: Just to give an example, you could do something like:

```
Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
sheet.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(cellNumber).setCellValue(someValue);
```

And you can get fancy and iterate through every row, cell, column, etc. I found it to be pretty flexible. Even offers styling options

Edit2: Just realized you don't need to set the excel cell value. Oh well, there it is anyways. Still a useful library to use one way or the other though.